# How implement translation link with Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I had setup translation for a symfony 2 application. It works well when i change the "local" setting in "parameters.yml", but i want to use a link on each page to switch languages (2 languages used).
Do you know a simple method to implement this link (and if it's possible, not change the current URLs in the application)?

Notes: There is the FOSUserBundle.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to serve a page in different languages with the same URL? This is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a little local switcher for my own project.

It's easy to do just create a twig with this link generated for each languages and you'll be able to switch your website local easily :

```
  <a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'fr'})) }}">
  LANGUAGE
</a>
```

Also, if you want a bundle to help you with your translation try this one : 
https://github.com/lexik/LexikTranslationBundle

Comment: I'm interested by your local switcher, but when i use your link, i have a 500 error. Your link : <a href="{{ path(app.request. app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}">Test</a>